# Software to detect recorded/learn click sounds (3 difference) and trigger an action

Tags: audio, machine-learning

Is there any software which can record/learn click sounds (up to 3 difference sound, example from metal clickers) and then detect them later?

Put in another way; a software which can detect and count difference click sounds, after learning these difference clicks sounds (up to 3).